# can't login into debian with the account any more

Tags: shell

My system is debian7.8,there are two accounts in it ,one is root one is debian7.
The command was runned yesterday.

```
rm -rf ///Trash://*
```

I found that only root can login into,the account debian7 can't.

```
userdel debian7
useradd debian7
passwd  debian7
```

question1:

I know that wrong command was executed,resulted in bad effect.
What did the system do when to exectue the command  `rm -rf ///Trash://*`

question2:
The strange thing : i can't still login into debian7 after running the three commands.

```
userdel debian7
useradd debian7
passwd  debian7
```

Comment: Your problem may be unrelated to the command  you ran.

Answer (score 1):

The command should do nothing because `///Trash://*` is that same as `/Trash:/` and that shouldn't be a path to anything.

With that being said, that command is dangerously close to `rm -rf /` (destroy everything you have access to).